# entity framework foreign key different types

Tags: frameworks, entity

I am having the hardest time dealing with foreign keys that are of different type.  In one table it is a string and in another table it is an int, and I cannot have the database corrected.

I have two tables, which I will call MainLine and CommentLine, in a one-to-many relationship.

```
public partial class MainLineDTO
{
   public MainLineDTO()
    {
       this.CommentLineDTO = new List<CommentLineDTO>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<CommentLineDTO> CommentLineDTO { get; set; }

    public string Timesheet_No_ { get; set; }
    public int Line_No_ { get; set; }     
}


public partial class CommentLineDTO
{
    public CommentLineDTO()
    {
    }

    public string No_ { get; set; }
    public String Code { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual MainLineDTO MainLineDTO { get; set; }
}
```

and these are my mapping files:

```
public class MainLineMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MainLineDTO>
{
    public MainLineMap ()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.Timesheet_No_, t.Line_No_});

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Timesheet_No_)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        this.Property(t => t.Line_No_).IsRequired();
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.ToTable("Main Table");
        this.Property(t => t.Line_No_).HasColumnName("Line No_");
        this.Property(t => t.Timesheet_No_).HasColumnName("Timesheet No_");

    }
}

public class CommentLineMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CommentLineDTO>
{
    public CommentLineMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new {t.No_, t.Code, t.Comment});

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.No_)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        this.Property(t => t.Code)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Comment)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(80);


        this.ToTable("Comment Table");
        this.Property(t => t.No_).HasColumnName("No_");
        this.Property(t => t.Code).HasColumnName("Code");
        this.Property(t => t.Comment).HasColumnName("Comment");

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Timesheet_WIP_LineDTO)  
            .WithMany(t => t.CommentLineDTO)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.No_, d.Code });
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is join the lines WHERE MainLine.Line_No_ = CommentLine.Code AND MainLine.Timesheet_No_ = CommentLine.No_.
The trouble is Line_No_ is an int, and Code is a String.  No matter what I've tried, the code either didn't compile or gave me an
exception later.  How should I modify my code to get the join to work?

Comment: How? With linq2sql? Please post your code.

Comment: I am sorry shay, I don't know how to answer you.  I inherited this project and I am trying to add the CommentLine to it.  The MainLine was already there.  I know the code makes a sql call to get the data, but I have not heard of "linq2sql".

Comment: Can you post the code that makes the sql call?

Comment: It's something resembling this:  Employee.Find(employeeID)  where Emloyee is System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SomeDTO>